# How to use HTML Dom in adobe flex?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

Can you use Html DOM in adobe flex to...

1) write/Auto fill in a form?

2) Read values in label? Textboxes? And use them in your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure if you want to access an HTML Page from inside a Flex app or if you want to access the interiors of a Flex app from inside an HTML Page.  Either way, [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) is your answer.

ExternalInterface allows Flex to call JavaScript in the enclosing page.  You can then use JavaScript to drill down into the HTML DOM and access the data you need.

ExternalInterface also allows a mechanism for the enclosing page to call functions in the Flex App.

[More docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/19_External_Interface_04.html)

If you want to use JavaScript specific DOM Accessing syntax inside of a Flex App to access parts of that Flex app, I would assume that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can, but check out for Security limitations.